# Polygon Triangle Count Optimization

Tags: math, optimization, polygon

Recently I wrote myself an Ear Clipping Triangulator as personal research. After visualizing some of the results, I can't help but feel that the object could be reproduced with fewer than `n-2` triangles. Unfortunately, my small graphics book library could not lead me to any possible algorithms or methods to achieve this goal.

I know of `simplification` of course, but that affects the actual shape and appearance of the model. I wish to just remove extraneous triangles. Is this at all possible? Or is a more efficient triangulation method required?

For example, the top diamond shaped object is composed of 34 triangles. On paper I was able to triangulate it using just 18.

[image]

Comment: Clearly `n-2` is the optimal for general polygons, but you would like to find the optimal cut for your particular polygon, right? There is gonna be some slow search algorithms that will do that, but perhaps your polygons aren't general. Are they for example always rectilinear and without holes?

Comment: @Thomas Ahle The data will always be rectilinear (fancy word) but has the possibilities of having holes. An image is fed into an extractor that reads out the polygon with any possible holes/transparencies. Since the data is comprised of individual pixels the resulting polygon will be blocky (as desired). I feel like I may be too obsessed with minimizing triangle-count for performance, but it never hurts!

Comment: Ok, can you also add a picture of your hand-cut 18 triangles version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem in FEM and CFD. There are some open-source packages available that you could look to see how they do this problem. Two that come to mind are [OOF](http://www.nist.gov/mml/ctcms/oof/) and [OpenFOAM](http://www.openfoam.com).

Comment: Ill have to check those out when I get the chance later tonight.